# Django prefetch_related causing extra queries in M2M relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models:

Person model has many to many (M2M) relationship with Questions.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question, related_name='persons')
```

I see from the Django debug toolbar that when I issue:

```
persons = Person.objects.filter(name="Foo").prefetch_related("questions")
```

it does 2 queries, one to Person table, another to Questions table as excepted.

However, if I traverse the list in the template, additional select queries for each row of Person is being made.

```
{% for person in persons %}
{{ person.name }}
   {%  for question in person.questions.all %}
       {{ question.text }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is the second SQL for the questions, so definitely prefetch is working, but somehow it needs the additional queries to show each question.

```
SELECT ("myapp_person_questions"."person_id") AS "_prefetch_related_val", 
"myapp_question"."id", "myapp_question"."asker_id", 
 "myapp_question"."question", "myapp_question"."timestamp" 
INNER JOIN "myapp_person_questions" ON ("myapp_question"."id" = 
 "myapp_person_questions"."question_id") WHERE              
 "myapp_person_questions"."person_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4) ORDER BY 
 "myapp_question"."timestamp" DESC


SELECT "myapp_question"."id", "myapp_question"."asker_id", 
"myapp_question"."question", "myapp_question"."timestamp" FROM 
"myapp_question" INNER JOIN "myapp_person_questions" 
ON ("myapp_question"."id" = "myapp_person_questions"."question_id") 
WHERE "myapp_person_questions"."person_id" = 1 ORDER BY "myapp_question"."timestamp" DESC
```

I disabled all custom `Manager`s, so I am quite sure additional filtering is not done on the `QuerySet`.

One thing to note is that I do not explicitly generate the join table myself, could that be the issue? (using `through`)

Comment: How does the question model look? It might be possible that it references the persons model in some way which makes it query the DB again.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem: I was executing additional queries each time I tried to reference something I thought I'd pulled back in my query!  I think I found the solution.  In order to prevent additional lookups for *each instance*, you can extend your prefetch_related to include the lookup tables you need.  Indeed, this produces *one more query*, but it doesn't produce 10,000 queries, assuming you have 10,000 persons you are trying to access.

```
    students = Person.objects.select_related('gender',
                                             'old_race',
                                             'ethnicity',
                                             'father_education_level',
                                             'mother_education_level',
                                             ).prefetch_related('personethnicity_set',
                                                                'personethnicity_set__ethnicity',
                                                                'studentsemester_set',
                                                                'studentsemester_set__semester',
                                                                'studentsemester_set__first_mode_admission',
                                                                'studentsemester_set__classification',
                                                                'studentsemester_set__academic_status',
                                                                'studentsemester_set__studentsemestermajor_set',
                                                                'studentsemester_set__studentsemestermajor_set__major_type',
                                                                'studentsemester_set__studentsemestermajor_set__major',
                                                                'studentsemester_set__studentsemestermajor_set__major__registrar_school').filter(ftic_cohort=oursem).order_by('-studentsemester__semester__ccyys')
```

In the above code, I am able to get all the lookup tables (one-to-ones) for my person records using the select_related.  Then, I am able to get my many-to-manys using the prefetch_related (of personethnicity and studentsemester), *and* I am able to get the lookup tables that go with those many-to-many tables by doing personethnicity__ethnicity, etc.

In a query that pulls back 8000 students or so, I am only doing 15 SQL queries with this code.  I then reference my prefetched fields by doing (in my case, within a loop for stud in students) like this:

```
studict['ethnicities'] = ''
for myeth in stud.personethnicity_set.all(): 
    studict['ethnicities'] += str(myeth.ethnicity) + ' '
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Something else to be aware of is if there is an order by on the query when accessing it in the template.  For example doing:
`person.questions.all.first`
puts an ascending sort on the ID, so in your prefetch you would need to use the Prefetch object to designate a sort order that is the same, like so:

```
persons = Person.objects.filter(name="Foo").prefetch_related(Prefetch("questions", queryset=Question.objects.all().order_by("id")))
```